# AWS SES - Receiving Email to S3 Possible Throttled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I have configured AWS SES for receiving emails, and publishing to an S3 bucket, which then triggers a lambda function to process the email.

I have used this successfully for years without issue. However, the most recent integration isn't sporadic email throughout the day, instead it's a large burst of emails from the same sender to the same receipt rule. This happens once a day, and there should be close to 100 emails at a time, and instead I'm getting 10-15 of them delivered to the s3 bucket.

I can't find any useful CloudWatch metrics or logs, and I can't find any mention of SES receiving limits or throttling. Is there a limit or a throttling threshold on AWS SES Receiving that isn't specified in the documentation?

Any insights here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What changed between the most recent integration and the one before? Can you share any config details of how you've set up S3 and SES?

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing has changed from the previous integrations and this most recent one. We have one domain set up in Route53, lets call it domain.com. Then we have one SES Email Receiving rule set, with a separate address for each integration. Lets call them tool1@domain.com and tool2@domain.com. Each receipt rule in the active rule set puts the email in a different folder/prefix in the same S3 bucket. All previous rules are still working, and the new rule does work for a few emails each day, but there are emails sent to tool2@domain.com that aren't properly put in s3